# Is there an alternative for net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ipv6, sysctl

On Linux (Kernel >= 4.3) I can "claim" an entire IPv6 subnet by routing it to localhost ([sf#403648](https://serverfault.com/questions/236626/how-to-bind-a-non-local-ipv6-address/776009)), and then by setting `net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1` so that I can bind on any of these addresses.

I would like to be able to do the same thing on FreeBSD, but I can't find any documentation on the matter.  Is there some way to claim an entire /64 and bind on individual addresses?